# UIViewCollection resize cells after rotation in modal view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, orientation, ios9

I have a UIViewCollection working beautifully when the screen is rotated.  Everything is resized perfectly.

However, when I segue to a modal view controller, then rotate, then dismiss, only "some" of the rotation tasks are completed.  it doesn't resize the cells.

I did setup a delegate in my modal view controllers that does call the parent view controller's didRotate...

```html
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientationInModal:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation {
[self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
    [self.collectionView setCollectionViewLayout:self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout animated:YES];
} completion:nil];
    [self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout];
    [self.collectionView invalidateIntrinsicContentSize];
}

- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientationInModal:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {

    [self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout];
    [self.collectionView invalidateIntrinsicContentSize];
}
```

And I have verified they are being fired when I rotate in a modal view controller.

again, the cell size is IS being re-calculated when I rotate from the collectionviewcontroler, it's only when rotating in a modal view controller that the cell size is not being re-calculated.  exact same code is being fired in both cases.

Comment: is your modal a child view controller of the original view controller ? if not add it as a child view controller then present it.

Comment: It is a child view controller.  The parent UICollectionViewController presents a modal child UIViewController.

Answer (score 1):

Solved...

Turns out the issue was only present in the simulator.  On an actual device it works as expected.